# Accessing Mongodb on Kubernetes gives authentication failed

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes

I'm a newbie in Mongo and Kubernetes
I've created this deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mongo-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mongo
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mongo
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: mongo
          image: mongo:latest
          ports:
            - containerPort: 27017
          volumeMounts:
            - name: 'mongo-data-dir'
              mountPath: '/data/db'
          env:
            - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME
              value: rootUser
            - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD
              value: rootPass987
            - name: MONGO_INITDB_AUTH_DATABASE
              value: admin
      volumes:
        - name: 'mongo-data-dir'
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: 'pvc-mongo'
```

The pod deploys correctly, and the persistent volumes and claims are working correctly.
if I enter the pod:

```
k exec -it mongo-deployment-5cc7bbd547-5nf6x -- /bin/bash
```

and execute

```
mongosh -u rootUser -p rootPass987 --authenticationDatabase admin
```

I get:

```
Connecting to:          mongodb://<credentials>@127.0.0.1:27017/?directConnection=true&serverSelectionTimeoutMS=2000&authSource=admin&appName=mongosh+2.1.1
MongoServerError: Authentication failed.
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**You are almost there brother,
My opinion u have too include host localhost at last**

```
mongosh -u rootUser -p rootPass987 --authenticationDatabase admin --host localhost:27017
```

Comment: Thanks, I don't know what did change, but today I don't get the error anymore also without specifying the host